# Datatables populating all rows but says "1 of 1 entries"

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am trying to populate a datatable with information gathered from my API. Currently I am able to populate the table with all the rows I need however they do not seem to be attaching to the table, other than the first result. This results in the datatable only showing 1 entry if any search is made. It also says "Showing 1 to 1 of 1 entries" at the bottom

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5u4q9k8h/1/)

JS

```
//Payment history
$.ajax({
  url: "https://zelcash.voidr.net/api/payments",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {

    var _miner = "t1XHpNtYY2N3EMDRoX9RM2hq4DWWPZSmawJ";

    var addr = _miner;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

      //Name
      console.log(data[i].name);

      var payments = data[i].payments;
      for (var j = 0; j < payments.length; j++) {

        if (payments[j].amounts[_miner]) {

          //Time
          //console.log(payments[j].time);
          var date = payments[j].time;
          var date = new Date(parseInt(date));
          var date = date.toGMTString();

          //blocks
          var block = [];
          var blocks = payments[j].blocks;
          for (var b = 0; b < blocks.length; b++) {
            //console.log(blocks[b])
            block.push(blocks[b]);
          }

          //txid
          var txid = payments[j].txid;

          //amount
          //console.log(payments[j].amounts[_miner]);
          var amount = payments[j].amounts[_miner].toFixed(8);

          var htmlToAdd = "";
          htmlToAdd = '<tr>';
          htmlToAdd+= '<td>'+block+'</td>';
          htmlToAdd+= '<td><a href=\"https://explorer.zel.cash/tx/'+txid+'\">'+amount+'</a></td>';
          htmlToAdd+= '<td>'+date+'</td>';
          htmlToAdd+= '</tr>';
          $("#boxesPayments").html($("#boxesPayments").html()+htmlToAdd);

          $('#paymentTable').DataTable();

        }
      }
    }

  },
  error: function() {
    //alert("Was unable to get info!");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is updated code [Fiddle/5](https://jsfiddle.net/5u4q9k8h/5/).

You are initializing your Datatable too soon: before you added all your rows. You need to init it after all data is appended to the DOM HTML.

```
//Payment history
$.ajax({
  url: "https://zelcash.voidr.net/api/payments",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {

    var _miner = "t1XHpNtYY2N3EMDRoX9RM2hq4DWWPZSmawJ";

    var addr = _miner;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

      //Name
      console.log(data[i].name);

      var payments = data[i].payments;
      for (var j = 0; j < payments.length; j++) {

        if (payments[j].amounts[_miner]) {

          //Time
          //console.log(payments[j].time);
          var date = payments[j].time;
          var date = new Date(parseInt(date));
          var date = date.toGMTString();

          //blocks
          var block = [];
          var blocks = payments[j].blocks;
          for (var b = 0; b < blocks.length; b++) {
            //console.log(blocks[b])
            block.push(blocks[b]);
          }

          //txid
          var txid = payments[j].txid;

          //amount
          //console.log(payments[j].amounts[_miner]);
          var amount = payments[j].amounts[_miner].toFixed(8);

          var htmlToAdd = "";
          htmlToAdd = '<tr>';
          htmlToAdd+= '<td>'+block+'</td>';
          htmlToAdd+= '<td><a href=\"https://explorer.zel.cash/tx/'+txid+'\">'+amount+'</a></td>';
          htmlToAdd+= '<td>'+date+'</td>';
          htmlToAdd+= '</tr>';
          $("#boxesPayments").html($("#boxesPayments").html()+htmlToAdd);


        }
      }

                $('#paymentTable').DataTable();
    }

  },
  error: function() {
    //alert("Was unable to get info!");
  }
});
```

Comment: Sigh. Thanks, I didn't notice that.